# Can we measure the computing power of the Cray-II using the PassMark measure?

Tags: units-of-measurement, cpu-speed

I want to measure the computing power of the [Cray 2](http://www.craysupercomputers.com/downloads/Cray2/Cray2_Brochure001.pdf), circa 1985,  using a measure we apply to modern computers (including phones).

Recently I've seen the [Passmark](http://www.passmark.com/download/pt_download.htm) measure used.

My question is: **Can we measure [or extrapolate] the computing power of the Cray-II using the PassMark measure?**

Comment: What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Computer benchmarks must always be adapted to the circumstance, I think.

IMHO the best way of measuring the performance of a Cray (blessing and peace be upon him) is to take some input fed to the Cray and see how much time will need another computer to give the same results.

Anyway, for the average smartphone user, who need 30 seconds to read - and understand - an SMS (excluding the time to find the glasses) the speed difference between a Cray, a [VIC-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_VIC-20) and his phone is almost irrelevant.